# Return complex items in Scrapy (webcrawler)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to make a specifically aimed webcrawler with scrapy that returns an object of my results. I'm getting stuck and am probably going about things totally backwards.

More specifically, for each of the subforums at [TheScienceForum.com](http://www.thescienceforum.com/) (math, physics, etc), I would like to get the titles of all the threads within each of the subforums and end up with an object that has the name of the forum and a list of all the titles of the threads within the forum.

The end goal is to do text analysis on the thread titles to determine the most common terms/jargon associated with each forum. Eventually I would like to do analysis of the threads themselves as well.

I have one class Item defined as the following:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ProjectItem(Item):
    name = Field() #the forum name
    titles = Field() #the titles
```

I may be misunderstanding how items work, but I would like to end up with one item for each subforum with all the thread titles from that subforum in a list in the same item.

The crawler I wrote looks like this but does not function as expected:

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

    from individualProject.items import ProjectItem

    class TheScienceForum(CrawlSpider):
        name = "TheScienceForum.com"
        allowed_domains = ["theScienceForum.com"]
        start_urls = ["http://www.thescienceforum.com"]
        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a']), 'parse_one'),Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//div[@class="threadpagenav"]']), 'parse_two')]

        def parse_one(self, response):
            Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            forumNames = Sel.select('//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a/text()').extract()

            items = []
        for forumName in forumNames:
            item = projectItem()
            item['name'] = forumName
            items.append(item)
        yield items

        def parse_two(self, response):
            Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            threadNames = Sel.select('////h3[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            for item in items:
                for title in titles:
                    if Sel.select('//h1/span[@class="forumtitle"]/text()').extract()==item.name:
                        item['titles'] += Sel.select('//h3[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
            return items
```

The idea is to start on the main page for the site where all the subforum names are. The first rule only allows links to the first subforum page and the parse function associated with it it meant to create an item for each of the subforums, subbing in the forum name for the 'name' attribute.

For the following requests, using the second rule, the spider is limited to navigating the pages containing all the threads (the paginated links) of the sub forums. The second parse method is meant to add the thread titles to the item (created in first parse method) that corresponds with the name of the current subforum (Sel.select('//h1/span[@class="forumtitle"]/text()').extract())

The spider is crawling to all the main forum pages, but for each one I am getting the following error:

```
2013-11-01 13:05:37-0400 [TheScienceForum.com] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <GET http://www.thescienceforum.com/mathematics/>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but please put a little more description in your question: what problem are you having, what is the result you expect, and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far? Going through the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will help us better answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks- I've updated the question to try to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the crawling problem I was running into. The following code starts a spider on the forum homepage, creating a new item for each sub forum. The spider then follows the links, going to each page of the sub forum, collecting the thread titles along the way (adding them to the relevant item, all of which are being passed along with the next request). The code is as follows:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

from individualProject.items import ProjectItem

class TheScienceForum(BaseSpider):
    name = "TheScienceForum.com"
    allowed_domains = ["www.thescienceforum.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.thescienceforum.com"]
    #rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a']), 'parse_one'),Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//div[@class="threadpagenav"]']), 'parse_two')]

    def parse(self, response):
        Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        forumNames = Sel.select('//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        items = []
        for forumName in forumNames:
            item = ProjectItem()
            item['name'] = forumName
            items.append(item)


        forums = Sel.select('//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a/@href').extract()
        itemDict = {}
        itemDict['items'] = items
        for forum in forums:
            yield Request(url=forum,meta=itemDict,callback=self.addThreadNames)


    def addThreadNames(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        currentForum = Sel.select('//h1/span[@class="forumtitle"]/text()').extract()
        for item in items:
            if currentForum==item['name']:
                item['thread'] += Sel.select('//h3[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        self.log(items)


        itemDict = {}
        itemDict['items'] = items
        threadPageNavs = Sel.select('//span[@class="prev_next"]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        for threadPageNav in threadPageNavs:  
            yield Request(url=threadPageNav,meta=itemDict,callback=self.addThreadNames)
```

The issue I' running into now is how to save the data it is meant to be categorizing (to be later analized). I opened another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736545/save-scrapy-web-crawling-output) in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

As suggest by [Christian Temus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2797476/christian-ternus) be more descriptive in what problems you are facing. Looking into code I can make some suggestions

1. Rather than returning list of items, you should be doing "yield item" in the for loop.
2. Use a crawlspider
3. If you use a crawlspider rename 'parse' methond to something else, like, parse_titles.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to be more descriptive with my goal and approach. Why is it I should be yielding items in the loop? what does this allow me to do?

Comment: Can you remove your allowed domains or prepend with "www" ? Your allowed domain is "sci..." while the domains generated are of type "www.sci".

Comment: yield is more syntactic sugar change. Between, you will either return the list or yield a single item in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks Biswanath- I didn't catch that. The spider is now crawling to all the main forum pages but no further (to the paginated pages).

Comment: Either return a list or yield a single item. At the moment you are "yielding" a list.