# Saving Web Crawling Results (Scrapy)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I've written a spider that seems to be functioning properly, but I'm not sure how to save the data it is collecting.

The spider starts out at [TheScienceForum](http://www.thescienceforum.com/), grabs the main forum pages and makes an item for each. It then proceeds to go through all of the individual forum pages (passing the items along with it), adding the title of each thread to the matching forum item. The code is as follow:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request

from individualProject.items import ProjectItem

class TheScienceForum(BaseSpider):
    name = "TheScienceForum.com"
    allowed_domains = ["www.thescienceforum.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.thescienceforum.com"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        forumNames = Sel.select('//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        items = []
        for forumName in forumNames:
            item = ProjectItem()
            item['name'] = forumName
            items.append(item)
        

        forums = Sel.select('//h2[@class="forumtitle"]/a/@href').extract()
        itemDict = {}
        itemDict['items'] = items
        for forum in forums:
            yield Request(url=forum,meta=itemDict,callback=self.addThreadNames)  

    def addThreadNames(self, response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        Sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        currentForum = Sel.select('//h1/span[@class="forumtitle"]/text()').extract()
        for item in items:
            if currentForum==item['name']:
                item['thread'] += Sel.select('//h3[@class="threadtitle"]/a/text()').extract()
        self.log(items)


        itemDict = {}
        itemDict['items'] = items
        threadPageNavs = Sel.select('//span[@class="prev_next"]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        for threadPageNav in threadPageNavs:  
            yield Request(url=threadPageNav,meta=itemDict,callback=self.addThreadNames)
```

It seems that because I never simply return the object (only new requests are yielded) that the data never persists anywhere. I've tried using the following JSON pipeline:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

And also running the spider with the following:

```
scrapy crawl TheScienceForum.com -o items.json -t json
```

but so far nothing is working. Where might I be going wrong?

Any ideas or positive criticism is warmly welcomed.

Comment: You don't need any additional pipeline. Scrapy already provides the pipeline to store items and the default format is `jsonlines` which is one json object per line. So you only need the `-o` option. The main question is: where do you return the items?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `yield item` in at least one of your callbacks.

Comment: The issue is the data I would like to end up with would be one JSON object for each forum being scraped containing the title of the forum and then all of the thread titles. If I'm yielding an item every time then only the last time would it be the full item, right?

Comment: You can `yield item` when it contains all you data.

Answer (score 1):

@bornytm -

```
self.addThreadNames
```

is your function to which you are passing the urls or intermediate results. If you want to save it to the file csv or json , you can do like follows

```
yield "result"  ("result" can be replaced with your variable to which you are storing data. If you have multiple value , use yield in for loop. )
```

After that

```
scrapy crawl TheScienceForum.com -o output.csv -t csv
```

This will help you